# Making a string in a list to two strings in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, split

I have a list like:

```
['Mark', 'Reynold', 'Peter', 'Randall Macenroe'] #The list is a lot longer, so I can't go by index
```

And I want to change that list into another list:

```
['Mark', 'Reynold', 'Peter', 'Randall', 'Macenroe']
```

How can I do that? I sure can use that space between the two names (there will be always a space between two names), but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> lst = ['Mark', 'Reynold', 'Peter', 'Randall Macenroe']
>>> [y for x in lst for y in x.split()]
['Mark', 'Reynold', 'Peter', 'Randall', 'Macenroe']
>>>
```

Comment: That was easier than i thought! Works perfectly. Really big thanks!